# Counterexample to "integration splitting"

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, differential-geometry

My professor proved in class that if $f:\mathbb{R}^d \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{B_R(0)} f(\vec{x})d\vec{x} = \int_0^R\int_{\partial B_\rho(0)} f \ d\sigma d\rho$$ where $B_r(0)$ is the ball of center $0$ and radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $d\sigma$ is the surface element of $\partial B_\rho(0)$. My first reaction was "yeah sure, whatever, that's obvious" but then he ended with "this is not true for more general convex domains, if you want try to find a counterexample."

I can't really think of a way this isn't true (at least in a sensible space), so I ask you: can you find some (full) regular polygon $P_\rho \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ centered in $0$ with radius $\rho$ and some nice enough $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ for which the identity $$\iint_{P_R} f(x, y)dxdy = \int_0^R\int_{\partial P_\rho} f \ ds d\rho$$ doesn't hold? Can you provide sufficient conditions for when it does?

Comment: Let's say that you can write $\partial P_\rho = \{x \colon g(x) = \rho\}$ for some locally Lipschitz continuous $g :\Bbb{R}^d \to \Bbb{R}$. Then (if I am not too tired right now), the co-area formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) should show that your formula holds if and only if $|\nabla g(x)| = 1$ almost everywhere.

Comment: What you want to think about is whether $dA/d\rho$ is equal to the perimeter. This works for circles, of course. What about an equilateral triangle? an ellipse?